# How to get time in format HH:mm:ss from timestamp 20180805231400 -0300

Tags: android, time, timezone, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

Below is my code but it throws an exception saying that unable to parse date format.

```
     try{

        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss zzzz", Locale.getDefault());
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

        String inputText = channelListArrayList.get(0).getTv().getProgramme().get(j).getStart();
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
        String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: `20180805231400 -0300` is not a TimeStamp its a Format. TimeStamp usually called for epoch time .

Comment: your inputFormat should be outputFormat and vice versa

Comment: make sure `channelListArrayList.get(0).getTv().getProgramme().get(j).getStart();` is return correct value

Comment: @ShubhamVala  it is returning 20180805231400 -0300 value as String.

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: Word usage: a [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is “information identifying when a certain event occurred”, so yes, the string in the title serves well as a timestamp.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("20180805231400 -0300", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss xx", Locale.getDefault())).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()))` gives `2018-08-05-23:14:00`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can do it like this,

```
    oldfmt = "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzzz";
    newfmt = "HH:mm:ss";
    getTimeFromUtc(oldfmt, newfmt, "20180805231400 -0300");

public void getTimeFromUtc(String oldFormat, String newformat, String datetime) {
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
    inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(newformat, Locale.getDefault());
    TimeZone defaultTimezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    outputFormat.setTimeZone(defaultTimezone);
    String inputDateStr = datetime;
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(inputDateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (date != null) {
        outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), outputDateStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
try{

 DateFormat inputFromat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss zzzz", Locale.getDefault());
 DateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

 String inputText = channelListArrayList.get(0).getTv().getProgramme().get(j).getStart();
                Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
                String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```